# Relative path link to .xls file from org-mode

Tags: org-mode

I want to be able to link to an .xls file from org-mode.

Reading up online this seems to be the way to get the links to open correctly, however even if I change the link type to `file+sys' the file still gets opened within Emacs, instead of in Excel.

```
[[file+sys:./foo/bar.xls]]
```

Comment: This works for me. Are you using `C-c C-o` (`org-open-at-point`) to follow the link? Does it work if you use an absolute path, or a file with a different extension? What OS?

Comment: "It is not working" is not a very helpful description.  Please describe *how* it is not working for you, e.g. "even if I change the link type to `file+sys' the file still gets opened within Emacs, instead of in Excel".

Comment: @paprika duly noted regarding the question specificity.

Comment: @glucas yes. C-C C-o, I'm on Mac OSX.  Let me try an absolute path...

Comment: @glucas using absolute path works. I wonder why? I'd prefer to not have to use a fully-qualified path for all my Excel links.

Comment: Interesting, not sure why the relative path would behave differently here. Another way to do this is customize `org-file-apps` and add a rule to always use the system action to open *.xls files. E.g. `(add-to-list 'org-file-apps  '("\\.xls\\'" . default))`  In that case you should't need to include `+sys` in the link.

Answer (score 8):

You can configure how Org handles file links by customizing the variable `org-file-apps`.

By default Org will check `auto-mode-alist` and open the file in Emacs if it finds a match. If you would rather use the default system application for `.xls` files you can add something like this to your init file:

```
(add-to-list 'org-file-apps '("\\.xls\\'" . default))
```

You can also use prefix arguments to choose how to open a link on a case-by-case basis:

- `C-c C-o` will open the link according to your configuration
- `C-u C-c C-o` will visit the file in Emacs
- `C-u C-u C-c C-o` will let the system decide how to open the file

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [openwith](https://bitbucket.org/jpkotta/openwith) package for configuring associations of file types with external applications. This then opens the files in the defined applications and works for `find-file`, `dired`, and naturally also for `C-C C-o` in org-mode. The associations are defined in a list of lists (q.v. documentation of the `openwith-associations` variable). E.g. here are my settings for my ubuntu installation.

```
(("\\.pdf\\'" "evince" (file))
 ("\\.mp3\\'" "xmms" (file))
 ("\\.\\(?:mpe?g\\|mp4\\|MP4\\|avi\\|wmv\\)\\'" "mplayer" ("-idx" file))
 ("\\.odp\\|\\.odt\\|\\.doc\\|\\.docx\\'" "libreoffice" (file)))
```

Openwith is available from MELPA.

Relative links in org mode then work easily, e.g.

```
[[file:images/mypicture.pdf][this picture]]
```